# Decode packets as T30 messages in wireshark

Tags: fax

I need to decode a pcap file as T30 using wireshark or any other tool. In supported formats, wireshark has listed T30. So it should be possible to decode the packets as T30 messages. Could anybody please help me out how?

Comment: http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/22391/decode-packets-as-t30-messages-in-wireshark

Comment: @Iain That sure looks like the same person.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I can't imagine why the same person would need to ask the question again here having been given a perfectly good explanation over there.

Answer (score 1):

You don't decode the pcap file as a frame type; you decode frames.

It should be sufficient to merely right click on the frames and use the decode as option to force wireshark to use a particular protocol, if for some reason it doesn't guess correctly.

Usually, incorrect parsing is a sign that wireshark actually doesn't support decoding the data you have.